Filling the std::string's buffer efficiently
An API I'm using provides a function to get textual data:
foo_get_bar(FOOHandle cp, char bar[1024]);

The 1024 is a grotesque ovevrkill in most cases. Also, I'd like the data to live in a std::string anyway.
It bothers me, that the standard (anti)pattern would pass an automatic char buf[1024] to the function, and then initialize the C++ string by copying the buf into it, again...
I'd like to declare the std::string object -- bar -- to be of that large size from the start, pass the bar.data() to the API-call, and then resize bar to the actual size of the text.
How would I do that? My problems:

How to declare an std::string object with size, but without content -- using the fill-constructor string(size_t len, char c) will dutifully fill the entire kilobyte, which will defeat the purpose.
How to "auto truncate" the string -- the msg.resize(strlen(msg.c_str())) seems ugly and not C++-ish.


std::string was not meant to hold uninitialized data, there's nothing in its API to allow that.

C++23 has you covered https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/resize_and_overwrite.

std::vector, for example, can be resized first -- and then populated with values...
